# Data normalisation into third normal form

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf, candidate-key

I have done data normalization on dummy data and would like to know if I did it correctly. If it is done correctly, I would also like to ask two things below, because it is about 3NF.

**1NF:** This table should be 1NF.

| userId | userName | keyNumber | keyCode | accessGroup | doors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Alice | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Alice | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Bob | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Bob | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Alice | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Alice | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 |

**2NF:** I selected composite key (`userID` and `Doors`) as they represent minimal candidate key and got three tables applying FD rule.

Primary_key: `userID`

| userId | userName | keyNumber | keyCode | accessGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Primary_key: `doors`

| doors |
| --- |

Primary_key: (`userid`, `doors`)

| userId | doors |
| --- | --- |

**3NF:** Applying the rule of transitive dependency on 1st table in **2NF**, I got out 4 tables (showing only first two, because the last two remain unchanged)

Primary_key: `userID`

| userId | userName |
| --- | --- |

Primary_key: `keyNumber`

| keyNumber | keyCode | accessGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |

**Questions:**

1. Is this database normalisation correct? If not could you point me where I did mistake?
2. If answer on first question is True: Should the last table in **3NF** be transformed into two tables, given it is not in correct Third normal form. Two non-key atributes have FD `keycode` -> `accessGroup`

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when a process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your reference. [ask] [help] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) Basic questions are faqs, research before considering asking & reflect research.

Comment: Please act on all my comments on [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73241985/3404097) asking about how to normalize. Especially: Where & how are you 1st stuck/unsure in what process you quote? PS We don't normalize to 3NF by going through lower NFs. ["1NF" has many meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)--quote yours. What textbook/reference are you following--name & edition? You don't give FDs but they drive the process. A CK is a (so-called) minimal superkey, "minimal CK" doesn't mean anything. Don't know what "FD rule" or "apply a FD rule" mean.

Comment: I have only written helpful, appropriate & neutral comments & I explained & justified why I commented. After informing yourself re how the site works, if you think I have been inappropriate, besides flagging a post or comment for a moderator you can consider asking an on-topic question about your questions and/or my comments at [meta] (but beware "meta effect" attention you will get on your questions). See help & Q&A there & at [meta.se] re how the sites work. Good luck.

Comment: Comments are about posts not posters & can be for all readers not just posters. Bye.